# Calculate HTTPS POST Request size

Tags: java, java-me, https, midlet

I have a middlet that sends data to a servlet.

Anyone knows how can I calculate the size of request of the middlet in a servlet?

I'm tring to sum of request header + request size + certificate size
Is it correct?

With this I'm trying to recreate the request:

http://wikis.sun.com/display/WebServerdocs/Analyzing+SSL+Requests+and+Responses

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there is no simple way.

In fact, I'm not even sure this is a meaningful thing to measure.  The request header and body are part of the HTTP application protocol.  The certificate is sent as part of SSL / TLS setup ... before the HTTP stuff starts.  And once SSL / TLS has started, the HTTP protocol is run "on top of" the SSL / TLS channel.

Even just measuring the amount of data in a HTTP request is tricky.  A typical HTTP stack does not assemble the entire request message in one place, and does not keep a running total of the amount of data sent.  Depending on the HTTP stack that you are using, you could (in theory) arrange to use a custom socket factory and socket streams that count the bytes sent.

Comment: Thank you for the response. To make the thinks more easy, how can I count the TOTAL size of the HTTP request ? .... Request header + Request size data?

Comment: @iberck - See the last paragraph.  Configure your client to use a special socket factory.  It is not straightforward, and doing it with HTTPS in the mix is likely to make it even more complicated.  I don't know enough about Java/ME to give you a recipe.

Comment: I don't know how can I create a special socket factory

Answer (score 1):

Read more about [SSL handshake](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itame2.doc_5.1%2Fss7aumst18.htm):

I think the conversation round-trip may worry you as well as packet sizes.

Once handshake phase is finished and connection is reused (keepalive) only HTTP data is sent, encrypted of course.

Answer (score -4):

like this:

> $value) {
>            $size += (strlen($key) + strlen($value) + 3);
>         }
>        printf("size=%d",$size);
>        exit;
>     ?>